all versus each
Sentence 1:

the plurality of users all belong to one team from a list of Team A, Team B, and Team C.


Sentence 2:

the plurality of users each belong to one team from a list of Team A, Team B, and Team C.

questions:

In Sentence 2, does "belong" need to be "belongs", due the "each"?
Does Sentence 1 necessarily mean that all of the users belong to the same team?


Why not drop 'plurality' and use '[Without exception,] each of the users belongs to one team, either Team A, Team B, or Team C.'  'The plurality of ...' is rare and rarefied, and sounds particularly unidiomatic when twinned with 'each' or 'all'. With 'The staff all belong to ASDEF Union', the choice is clear; one needs 'Each member of staff belongs to ASDEF' for the associated paraphrase.

There seems a lot of debate about which part of speech "each" is in different situations, but there's a reasonable case to be made that each is an adverb rather than a quantifier here and hence doesn't affect agreement. There are several closely argued questions on the topic, such as this.

But do look into the use of the word plurality.

"plurality" is normally only used to refer to a number of people in the the context of an election (compare it with "majority"). It's not clear what you mean here.

"Does Sentence 1 necessarily mean that all of the users belong to the same team?" Yes.

Is this a patent application? Plurality is often used there. If so, I would caution that if the verb tense is up for legitimate debate, you would likely be far better off to rephrase to make things explicit and clear.
